# Not able to locate element in a hybrid app using Appium with Java for Android mobile device

Tags: java, android, appium

I am new to appium and trying to automate an app. My script in Java is not able to identify textbox field.

```
 MobileElement code =  driver.findElement(By.id("some-id"));

 WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
 wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(code));

 code.click();

  code.sendKeys("abc");
```

I am getting following error in console.

May 23, 2018 5:34:39 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'N0PCINF651RBHT', ip: '100.118.94.148', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: nz.co.mcom.phone.login.Spla..., appPackage: com.fiserv.touchbanking, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: nz.co.mcom.phone.login.Spla..., appPackage: com.fiserv.touchbanking, deviceName: Samsung, platformName: android, platformVersion: 7.0}, deviceManufacturer: samsung, deviceModel: SM-G950F, deviceName: ce03171399d964fa0c, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2960, deviceUDID: ce03171399d964fa0c, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 7.0, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 58013355-1b58-4c8d-895f-7a57144e0595
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=com.fiserv.touchbanking:id/AppCodeTextBox}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:317)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementById(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:70)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementById(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementById(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at mytests.LaunchTouchbankingApp.main(LaunchTouchbankingApp.java:50)

Bootstrap logs in Appium server are as follow:-

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.fiserv.touchbanking:id/AppCodeTextBox' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false

Your help would be highly appreciable. thanks.

Comment: I tried multiple ways to locate the textbox element like use of resource-id, text, class name. Also created dynamic Xpath but not sure where the issue is. My environment has Selenium Jar Version - '3.12.0' and Java Client Version - '6.0.0-BETA5'.

Comment: use uiautomator tool from android-sdk-tool set, and check if there exists com.fiserv.touchbanking:id/AppCodeTextBox value for resource-id of your element on the given app in selected device?

Comment: And also attach the output of driver.getPageSource() along with your question.

Comment: @nandal, I have used uiautomator viewer to figure out resource-id and it is com.fiserv.touchbanking:id/AppCodeTextBox when the required element is selected.

Comment: I am not getting page source and following is the BootStrap logs: -     [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["080f1250-eaeb-4a0f-b7f0-9c72c640c0cb"]
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: source

Answer (score 0):

The exception returned seems to be simply because the element was not found in the UI at the moment of your search.

Keep in mind that, in the snippet you have posted, the element identified by the id 'some-id' will be searched for once the first line is executed, not later on when you try to click on the element. Are you performing any sort of implicit wait on that `driver.findElement(By.id("some-id"));`? If not, are you sure that element is available when you are first trying to find it in the UI?

To make sure the element is actually available, you could check if it appears in the page source just before you are doing your findBy. In Java, you could do it like so:

`System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());`

Comment: In my case app is getting launched successfully. Then a pop-up comes and on this pop-up script clicks on 'OK' successfully. Then the page in question comes and nothing happens. I tried with pagesource(), page title identification etc before identifying textbox element but script just fails. Not sure where the issue is.

Comment: I believe control doesn't come after clicking OK button of pop-up to screen where I am trying to locate textbox element. I tried with driver.switch().defaultcontent() but it also doesn't work.